# cant find software i downloaded

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu & I downloaded software from the Ubuntu Software Centre & now I can't find it anywhere.

The file is called Partition Scanner and Disk Recovery Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Partition Scanner and Disk Recovery Tool open the terminal and type `testdisk`. testdisk is a command-line tool that is run from the terminal.

You can also run this command from the terminal to find the name of the program:

```
apt-cache search Partition Scanner
```

...which returns the following results:

```
testdisk - Partition scanner and disk recovery tool
testdisk-dbg - Partition scanner and disk recovery tool
```

Comment: Hi I don't understand all this sorry where is the Terminal.

Comment: hold CTRL and ALT and tap T - one will open

Comment: The terminal (it opens using Ctrl+Alt+T) is Ubuntu's equivalent of the Windows cmd window for running commands from the command line.

Comment: Have fun. Once you know the package's name from running `apt-cache search` you can also display a verbose description of what the package does from the terminal by running: `apt-cache show name-of-the-package`.